# Command prompt In JAVA

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have to open  a CMD with administrator previlege by CMD command . So i try this code and then It asks for password but   how can i provide the password in the same process. And then I have to catch the newly opened CMD.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /noprofile /user:Partha >fg.txt")
p.waitFor();
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("password");
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Please post the code as text in your question, do not attach it as an image.

Answer (score 2):

You could better use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) util that allow to pass the password as argument :

```
psexec \\computername -u domain\user -p password
```

Otherwise you could just try passing the password as STDIN :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C echo YOUR_PASS | runas /noprofile /user:Partha >fg.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @aleroot's answer, you should use ProcessBuilder rather than Runtime.exec